# How to add polyline into Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, apache-zeppelin, polyline

I'm using zeppelin and angular interpreter. 
I have tried three different ways. None of them was successful. But simple markers showed up.

1st one

```
var array =  [];
all_properties.forEach(item =>{
    array.push(new L.LatLng(item[0], item[1]));
});
 var firstpolyline = new L.polyline(array, {
color: 'red',
weight: 5,
opacity: 1,
smoothFactor: 1
});
firstpolyline.addTo(map);
```

2nd one

```
var poly = new L.polyline(all_properties, {
color: 'green',
weight: 5,
opacity: 1,
smoothFactor: 1
});
poly.addTo(map);
```

3rd one

```
var polylinePoints = [
        [lat, long],
        [lat1, long1]
      ];            
var polyline = L.polyline(polylinePoints).addTo(map);
```

There is no error...

Any ideas? Thx

Edit: When I show points as markers, all of them showed up one the map. This set of markers should me polyline tho...

```
arr_markers = [];
all_properties.forEach(item =>{
arr_markers.push(L.marker([ item[0], item[1]], {icon: basicIcon}));
});

polyGroup = L.layerGroup(arr_markers).addTo(map);
```

[image: polyline from markers]

Comment: How does your `all_properties` look like?

Comment: oh yeas, it is a field of fields [[0,1],[0,1],...] - this is why I forEach and then acces indexes 0, 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird thing happened. I just logged off and logged in and the polygon showed up. Actually all of them. Maybe something was cached in my browser (Firefox), or in Zeppelin, or interpreter (restarting of angular interpeter did not help tho...)

[image: leaflet with polygon]